# How could Van Kampen Theorem imply that $\Phi:*_\alpha\pi_1(X_\alpha)\to\pi_1(\bigvee_\alpha X_\alpha)$ is an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology

How could Van Kampen Theorem imply that $\Phi:*_\alpha\pi_1(X_\alpha)\to\pi_1(\bigvee_\alpha X_\alpha)$ is an isomorphism?

[image]

The above is taken from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology page 43.

Are we using the last part of the Theorem that says $\Phi$ induces an isomorphism $\pi_1(X)\approx*_\alpha\pi_1(A_\alpha)/N$? But what is the $N$ in this case, and what is $\bigvee_\alpha X_\alpha$?

Could somebody please give some light on this? This might not be a really difficult question, but I have thought about it for quite some time and still confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point is to realize that $N$ (the kernel of $\Phi$) is trivial here. Therefore by the first isomorphism theorem, the surjective homomorphism $\Phi$ induces the isomorphism we seek.

Why is $N$ trivial? Well, $N$ is generated by elements of the form $i_{\alpha \beta}(\omega)i_{\beta \alpha}(\omega)^{-1}$ for $\omega \in \pi_1(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta)$. So it suffices to show that $i_{\alpha \beta}(\omega)i_{\beta \alpha}(\omega)^{-1}$ is always the identity element of the free group $*_\alpha \pi_1(A_\alpha)$. If $\alpha = \beta$, then this is plainly true, as then $$i_{\alpha \beta}(\omega)i_{\beta \alpha}(\omega)^{-1} = i_{\alpha \alpha}(\omega)i_{\alpha \alpha}(\omega)^{-1} = 1.$$ Now if $\alpha \neq \beta$, $A_\alpha \cap A_\beta$ is contractible (as Hatcher points out), and so $\pi_1(A_\alpha \cap A_\beta) = \{1\}$ is a trivial group. Thus in this case the generators are just $i_{\alpha \beta}(1)i_{\beta \alpha}(1)^{-1} = 1$.